# SQL Server: Count number across columns

Tags: sql-server

Im looking for assistance with what I thought was a simple task. :(

I have a table in SQL Server instance that contains the following columns and data:

```
num1   num2   num3   num4   num5
1      34     15     22     45
23     4      2      100    23
1      23     23     100    5
```

I want to get results that count the number of time all numbers appear:

```
Number  Count
1       2
2       2
3       0
4       1
5       1
6       0
```

Comment: Have you tried writing any queries yet? could you update this post with what you have tried?

Comment: Additionally, your sample select makes no sense in relation to your sample data.

Comment: The results that you have look incorrect. Should row 1 count == 2 for the example data? Not sure if I am understanding your question.

Comment: And also state version of SQL Server.

Comment: Simply UNION all the columns into a one-column derived table, and then count.

Comment: I did try UNION ALL, which gets me results that that appear to be a combined table. Im fuzzy (new to SQL) on how to get it into a "temp table" and them count and display the results;

Comment: `code`select num1 from results
union all
select num2 from results
union all
select num3 from results
union all
select num4 from results
union all
select num5 from results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an UNPIVOT statement to get all your values into one column.  Then its a simple GROUP BY and COUNT

```
select value, count(*)
from nums
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in (num1, num2, num3, num4, num5)
) u
group by value
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6ad85/6)

Answer (score 4):

Making some assumptions about the desired results and your SQL Server version

```
SELECT Number,
       COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM   YourTable
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(num1),(num2),(num3),(num4),(num5)) V(Number)
GROUP BY Number
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to get me what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Example of my comment above:

```
SELECT Number, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM (
SELECT num1 AS Number FROM MyTable
UNION ALL 
SELECT num2 AS Number FROM MyTable
UNION ALL 
SELECT num3 AS Number FROM MyTable
UNION ALL 
SELECT num4 AS Number FROM MyTable
UNION ALL 
SELECT num5 AS Number FROM MyTable
) t
GROUP BY Number
```